# How to use comparison operators as list?

Tags: python

How to use comparison operator ( > and < ) as iterable in the below code. I want the dataframe to first get filtered by > percentage and then < percentage ?

```
bars_list = list(range(1,50,1))
percentage_list = [-1,-0.5,0,0.5,1]

for bars in bars_list:
    for percentage in percentage_list:
        final_df = pd.read_csv('D:\\2nd Set 9th Jan\\Long_every_5_minutes.csv')
        result_df = final_df[final_df['Return_last_n_bars'] > percentage]
```

Comment: what is this ... all those comparisons could just be `final_df[final_df['Return_last_n_bars'] > min(percentage_list)]`

Answer (score 0):

You can filter using lambda.
I do not have your csv so, I cooked up sample list of csvs.

```
bars_list = list(range(1,50,1))
percentage_list = [-1,-0.5,0,0.5,1]
csv=[-2,-1.2,-1.1, -1.0, -0.2, -0.4, -0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.4, 1.0, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.6, 2.5, 3.0 ]
for percentage in percentage_list:
    print("--pivot: ",percentage)
    # final_df = csv #pd.read_csv('D:\\2nd Set 9th Jan\\Long_every_5_minutes.csv')
    greater_list = filter(lambda entry: entry > percentage, csv)
    print(greater_list)
    lesser_list = filter(lambda entry: entry < percentage, csv)
    print(lesser_list)
```

If you run this, then you will get lists that are iterable

```
$ python compareToList.py 
('--pivot: ', -1)
[-0.2, -0.4, -0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.4, 1.0, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.6, 2.5, 3.0]
[-2, -1.2, -1.1]
('--pivot: ', -0.5)
[-0.2, -0.4, -0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.4, 1.0, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.6, 2.5, 3.0]
[-2, -1.2, -1.1, -1.0]
('--pivot: ', 0)
[0.1, 0.4, 1.0, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.6, 2.5, 3.0]
[-2, -1.2, -1.1, -1.0, -0.2, -0.4, -0.1]
('--pivot: ', 0.5)
[1.0, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.6, 2.5, 3.0]
[-2, -1.2, -1.1, -1.0, -0.2, -0.4, -0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.4]
('--pivot: ', 1)
[1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.6, 2.5, 3.0]
```